# AJAX Post not catching successfully with Django

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I have an AJAX request as so:

```
$('input#post').on('click', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    data : {
        email: $('input#id_email').val(),
        password: $('input#id_password').val(),
    }

    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url  : '#',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(){
            console.log('Something went wrong');
        }
    });
});
```

which corresponds to the following view:

```
def index(request, show_login=False):
    login_form = LoginForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        login_form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if login_form.is_valid():
            email = request.POST.get("email", "")
            password = request.POST.get("password", "")

            user = authenticate(username=email, password=password)

            if user is not None:
                auth.login(request, user)
                return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'status': 'success'}), content_type="application/json")
            else:
                return redirect('/')
        else:
            login_form.add_error(None, "No user found!")
    return render(request, 'freelancestudent/general/index.html', {'login_form': login_form,
                                                                   'show_login': show_login})
```

HTML for the form:

```
      <form id="login" method="post" action="#">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{login_form.as_p}}
        <input id="post" type="submit" value="Login" />
      </form>
```

Suppose a user logs in with the correct credentials and I want to return the JSON dump containing `{'status': 'success'}`. When it gets to that return statement it simply changes the page in my browser view to a plain text implementation of `{'status': 'success'}` which I've been told is to be expected.

My desire was to have the returned data logged in the console in the success callback so I could do with it what I wished. How do I achieve this?

Comment: You know you're not passing any data at all in that ajax call ?

Comment: You're right. The email and password is being picked up through the post request. The password is in plain text too, worryingly.

Comment: That doesn't matter, it's common practice to send the password in plain text, but you have to actually send it

Comment: request.is_ajax resolve to false for some reason? I'll attach my HTML.

Comment: You're getting a successful status because the form is being posted by the normal browser submit, not via the Ajax. When you fix that - which as Alasdair points out is probably caused by the Ajax being attached to the wrong event - you will find that the form will fail, because you are not sending any data in the Ajax call.

Comment: Should I be calling the AJAX on the form submit rather than the button click?

Comment: Yes, I would try using the form's submit event instead of the input's click event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking to see if my requests actually *were* AJAX (thanks Alasdair) and finding they weren't I played with attaching the event to the form submit instead of the input's click. This didn't work either so I decided I'd just make a post using an `<a>` element.

```
     <form id="login" method="post" action="#">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{login_form.as_p}}
          <a id="post" href="">post</a>
      </form>
```

Using slightly edited JS than above:

```
$('a#post').on('click', function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        data = {};
        data.email = $('input#id_email').val();
        data.password = $('input#id_password').val();

        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url  : '#',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: data,
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
                if(data['status'] === 'success'){
                    $('a.remodal-close').click();
                }
            },
            error: function(){
                console.log('Something went wrong');
            }
        });
    });
```

This resolve to an AJAX request being `True` in my views which meant when my JSON was returned, it was caught in the success function which allowed me to do what I intended.

**Getting a 403 error?**

I've decided to append this information here because this problem drove me mad for the best part of a week so I'm going to aggregate it here. If you're having trouble attaching your CSRF token and you're getting 403 errors check out [this](http://coreymaynard.com/blog/performing-ajax-post-requests-in-django/) link, however I've heard that the "Next Steps" aren't necessary.

In conclusion, sort your CSRF token, use an `<a>` element to post in a form instead of an `<input>` for sanity's sake and debug like you're life depended on it.

Answer (score 0):

You should definetely read once again docs / tutorials about Jquery and AJAX. Are not even sending any data to the server and have wrong Jquery element's selector.

Best for the beginners is [Tango with Django tutorial](http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book17/) (in my opinion).

Below is an **verbose** example. Instead of your desired `{"success": "succes"}` I used simple HttpReponse `"OK"` if the form is valid.

#### AJAX:

```
$("#your_form_id").on("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url: "/your_url/",
        method: "POST",
        data: $("#your_form_id").serialize(), // Serializing your form's data including CSRF
        success: function(result) {
            // Your codes after received data (result) from the server if any
            // For example:
            if (result != "OK") { // Form is not valid
                var obj = $.parseJSON(result) // Create an instance from JSON data

                // Do something with errors aka attr (attr returns name of field), obj[attr] returns value )
                for (attr in obj) {
                    // Blablabla
                }
            }
            else {
                // Do something if the form is valid ...

                // Unbind this function and enable submitting
                $("#your_form_id").unbind("submit");
                $("#your_form_id").submit();
            }
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
});
```

#### VIEWS:

```
import json

from django.http import HttpResponse, JsonReponse

from your_app import the_form

# Create your views here

def name_of_your_function(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = your_form(request.POST)
.
        if request.is_ajax():
            if form.is_valid():
                return HttpReponse("OK")
            else:
                return JsonResponse(json.dumps(form.erros), safe=False)
        else:
            # Do something with the valided form
    else:
        # Do semething if request is "GET"
```